# Append first column to file

Tags: text-processing, command-line, awk, sed, paste

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Heading1,Heading2
value1,value2
```

And another one that looks like this:

```
Row1
Row2
```

How can I combine the two to become:

```
Row1,Heading1,Heading2
Row2,value1,value2
```

Effectively appending a column in the place of the first column?

Comment: Since you tagged this `paste`, presumably you tried the `paste` command?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't end up with what I was after so I asked here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Job for `paste`:

```
paste -d, f2.txt f1.txt
```

- `-d,` sets the delimiter as `,` (instead of tab)

---

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {print a[FNR], $0}' f2.txt f1.txt
```

- `BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}` sets the input and output field separators as `,`
- `NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next}`: for first file (`f2.txt`), we are saving the record number as key to an associative array (`a`) with values being the corresponding record
- `{print a[FNR], $0}`: for second file, we are just printing the record with the value of record number-ed key from `a` prepended

---

**Example:**

```
% cat f1.txt             
Heading1,Heading2
value1,value2

% cat f2.txt             
Row1
Row2

% paste -d, f2.txt f1.txt
Row1,Heading1,Heading2
Row2,value1,value2

% awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {print a[FNR], $0}' f2.txt f1.txt 
Row1,Heading1,Heading2
Row2,value1,value2
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I was close: `paste -d"," f2.txt f1.txt` :)

Answer (score 3):

Another short `awk` approach.

```bsh
awk '{getline x<"file1"; print $0","x}' file2
```

- `getline x<"file1"` reads the entire line from *file1* and holds into **x** variable.
- `print $0","x` prints the whole line from *file2* by using `$0` then `x` which is the saved line of *file1* with comma between.